# Browserify and Gulp - handing errors

Tags: gulp, browserify, gulp-watch

So I have a gulpfile,

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var source =  require('vinyl-source-stream');


gulp.task('js', function () {
    gulp.src('js/main.js')
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(rename('js/bundle.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

})

gulp.task('watch', function () {

    gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['js']);
})
```

fairly bog standard stuff - but the problem I am having is rather than throw me an error the gulp file just breaks my gulp watch

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: module "./sticknav.js
```

In this instance it was a typo - should have been stickynav.js but it now means I have to go back and start **gulp watch** again. How catch the errors without it breaking.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is a common problem and can be solved with gulp plumber

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber.

Just pipe it via plumber and the NPM stream issues are resolved. So far so good for me.

I have also added a notification with sounds(OSX) for growl.

Full gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var source =  require('vinyl-source-stream');
var notify = require("gulp-notify");
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

    function errorAlert(error){

    notify.onError({title: "Error", message: "Check your terminal", sound: "Funk"})(error); //Error Notification
    console.log(error.toString());//Prints Error to Console
    this.emit("end"); //End function
};



gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src('js/main.js')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: errorAlert}))
        .pipe(browserify({debug:  true}))
        .pipe(rename('js/bundle.js'))
        //.pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
        .pipe(notify({title: "Success", message: "Well Done!", sound: "Glass"}));


})

gulp.task('watch', function () {

    gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['js']);
})
```